# how to get a value from database in select option based on clicked id

Tags: php, database

i`m trying to get a value from database to select option, this is my code, with this code i can show the value but not inside the select option, i want to show it inside the select option

```
<td width="5%" valign="middle"> Prov. <?php echo $provinsi;?> </td>
<td width="20%" valign="middle">
    <select name="provinsi_dom" id="provinsi_dom">
    <?php
        //mengambil nama-nama provinsi yang ada di database
        $sqlProvinsi_dom = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM provinsi ORDER BY nama_provinsi ASC");
        echo "<option value=''>--Pilih Provinsi--</option>";
        while($p=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlProvinsi_dom)){
            if ($p['id_provinsi']==$provinsi_dom) {
                $cek="selected";
            }else {
                $cek="";
            }
            echo "<option value='$p[id_provinsi]' $cek>$p[nama_provinsi]  </option> " ; 
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

[image: The output Look like this, i want it to show the jawa barat only(because that is the one that being selected right now) and all the provinsi data]

Comment: What does the generated output look like?

Comment: are you trying to create multi level drop down ?

Comment: try this, read this [article](http://sakkarupa.blogspot.com/2017/08/dropdown-bertingkat-dengan-php.html), and if you get an error you can come back here

Comment: the multi level drop down has already been made and it works, now i just want to show what user input before inside the select option

Comment: I didn't get the point

Comment: so i already made the multi level drop down, now i want to show what user inputed before to the select option

Comment: what the value of `$provinsi_dom` ?

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific

```
echo '<option value="'.$p[id_provinsi].'" "'.$cek.'">' $p[id_provinsi]' </option>';
```

Comment: make sure that column 'id_provinsi'  must be present in your 'provinsi' table

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few changes like....

```
<td width="5%" valign="middle"> Prov. <?php echo $provinsi;?> </td>
<td width="20%" valign="middle">
    <select name="provinsi_dom" id="provinsi_dom">
    <?php
        //mengambil nama-nama provinsi yang ada di database
        $sqlProvinsi_dom = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM provinsi ORDER BY nama_provinsi ASC");
        echo '<option value="">--Pilih Provinsi--</option>';
        while($p=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlProvinsi_dom)){
            if ($p['id_provinsi']==$provinsi_dom) {
                $cek="selected";
            }else {
                $cek="";
            }
            echo '<option value="'.$p[id_provinsi].'" '.$cek.'>'.$p[nama_provinsi].'</option> ' ; 
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

It will work Fine.